# How to fix this problem with opencv-python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pycharm, opencv

I'm trying to use opencv-python on python 3.9 in VSCode.

I try the simple program:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('smallgray.png', 0)
print(img)

cv2.imwrite('test1.png', img)
```

The program running in VSCode return the message:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-wvn_it83\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp:753: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'cv::imwrite'
```

I tried the same code in PyCharm and worked perfectly.
What is happening and how can I fix it?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are [a number of threads on this same error](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%28-215%3AAssertion+failed%29+%21_img.empty%28%29).

Comment: Where are your images located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For GRAYSCALE

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('imagename.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
print(img)

cv2.imwrite(test1.png', img)
```

FOR RGB

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('imagename.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
print(img)

cv2.imwrite('test1.png', img)
```

Comment: Using the code for grayscalle returns:

cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-wvn_it83\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

Comment: Check now, i edit the code...

Comment: Error again:
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-wvn_it83\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp:753: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'cv::imwrite'

Comment: I don't understand why that happens just on VSCode, on PyCharm worked

Comment: use the full path where the image and where it will be save

Comment: Oh, I don't believe was just that. The code worked, but the VSCode keeps with the message **"Module 'cv2' has no 'imread' member pylint(no-member)"**, but the code works. Thanks